# Laravel form validation set rules like first two character are alphabet and last four character numeric like AB1234

Tags: php, laravel, formvalidation-plugin

Please help me I am new in laravel. I set form validation like first two characters are alphabet and last four character numeric. Example AB1234

Comment: You should create your own rule maybe using regex. See [docs for creating a new rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: /[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}/m ..Use Laravel validator's regex validation method to validate your value

Answer (score 1):

As comments say, you can do this by regex:

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    'some_col' => ['string', 'regex:/^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$/'],
    // other rule
]);
```

According to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-regex), this rule use `preg_match` so you should follow the same formatting required by `preg_match`. Don't forget to use **array** to specify rules (just like example code).

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular expression in the Validator,

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'your_input' => [
        'required',
        'regex:/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}+$/',
    ]
]);
```

you need to add `^` and `$` on regex to make sure it match First 2 and 4 End

Comment: This code is working thank you very much.

Comment: you're welcome :)